# Using ASP.NET c# with Sketchup Ruby Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, ruby, sketchup

I'm an ASP.NET c# developer using VS2010 as my development platform.  I am interested in accessing Sketchup models using a web form interface.

Has anyone done this?   I am looking for a simple "Hellow World" web application that uses the Ruby Extension model.

Comment: Hey, are you refering to accessing model inside Sketchup?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at two tutorials I did to show how WebDialogs work in Sketchup with Ruby API:

[Creating Web Dialogs in Sketchup and making calls from and to Sketchup](http://engineeringtheworld.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/creating-web-dialogs-in-sketchup-and-making-calls-from-and-to-sketchup/)

[Using Web Dialogs in Sketchup round two](http://engineeringtheworld.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/using-web-dialogs-in-sketchup-round-two/)

Hope it helps

Ladislav